# dtsx package not executing properly when imported and run manually in SSIS 2019

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019, ssis-2019

We have migrated to sql server 2019 from sql server 2017. 
We have a dtsx package which has script task, data flow task and Execute sql task.

For test purpose, I have added a message box to print the value of a variable in the script task.
Message box is getting popped up when the package is executed in sql server 2017 but not in sql server 2019.

The script was targeted to .NET framework 4 but I have also checked by changing to 4.8 framework, which is installed in sql server VM.
My script task is running properly in SQL Server 2017 also in sql server 2016, 2014. Also it is running properly through dtexec command in sql server 2019.
It also runs properly through visual studio when pointing to database in sql server 2017 and sql server 2019.

*I am facing issue when I manually import the dtsx package in SSIS 2019 through SSMS and run it by right click the dtsx package under MSDB.*
When I import the package in sql server by using dtutil command and run it manually by right clicking the package under MSDB. It runs properly.

Its also working when I change the TargetServerVersion to latest sql server 2019, but then it is incompatible with the previous versions of sql server, which is undesirable.

Please help!
Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the question? Where it is not working properly?